# get date using Angular-UI Bootstrap Datepicker inside Modal opened from Grid cell

Tags: datepicker, modal-dialog, angular-ui, angular-ui-grid

Maybe this is overkill, but I am trying to
1. open a Modal window, when a link is clicked in UI-Grid
can be done by modifying http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/tutorial/110_grid_in_modal
2. Put a (ui.bootstrap.datepicker) inside the Modal
3. Retrieve the chosen date
4. update the Date Cell in that UI-Grid Row

so, Is Ui-Grid 'well suited'/'can do this' given the above requirements

tia

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope, not overkill. You can do this with UI-Grid pretty easily.  There's a guide on how to do hook up modal editors using [Angular Schema Form](https://github.com/Textalk/angular-schema-form) here: http://brianhann.com/create-a-modal-row-editor-for-ui-grid-in-minutes/ (caveat: I'm the author).

I've also created a new plunker that uses the angular-schema-form-datepicker library to show how you might do this: http://plnkr.co/edit/7t3BI2AUcnvNfav78Btr?p=preview

*(plunker has been throwing 404s for files that are part of a plunk so you might have to refresh it)*

The main things you have to do are set up your object schema:

```
scope.schema = {
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "myDate": {
      "title": "My Date",
      "type": "string",
      "format": "date"
    }
  }
}
```

Using the same property as your column Defs:

```
columnDefs = [
  { field: 'myDate', name: 'My Date' }
]
```

And specify your date format in your form:

```
form = [
  {
    key: 'myDate',
    format: 'yyyy-mm-dd'
  }
]
```